# displaying value from database to html modal in php not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a PHP page where I am displaying data according to the id fetched from the URL, the data is displayed fine, now I place of a field name called comment, I have given a button, which on click gives a modal. if I click the button the value should come according to the corresponding id in the modal, but when I click the button, the modal is coming blank, I have done the following code:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1000;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-earning">



  <thead>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <th>S.NO</th>
        <th>View</th>
        <th>Edit</th>

        <th>Full Name</th>

        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>Space</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Enquiry Date</th>

      </tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <?php
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from enquiry where Space IS NOT NULL");
$cnt=1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {

?>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $cnt;?>
      </td>
      <td><a href="enquiryview.php?editid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" title="View Full Details"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i></a></td>
      <td><a href="enquiryedit.php?editid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" title="Edit Full Details"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-1x"></i></a></td>

      <td>
        <?php  echo $row['name'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php  echo $row['phone'];?>
      </td>
      <td><input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Comment"></td>
      <td>
        <?php  echo $row['Space'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php  echo $row['email'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php  echo $row['date'];?>
      </td>

    </tr>
    <?php 
$cnt=$cnt+1;
}?>
</table>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"><!-- &times; --></span>

    <div class="form-style-10">
      Hi
      <?php  echo $row['name'];?>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

i have tried closing the while loop after the modal, but then the only one values is displayed in my table, and the modal is displaying that values comment and some html code.
can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

please use jQuery a, ajax and bootstrap modal and try the following code
give a class to your comment button and get id as attribute of button

```
   //your jquery function to trigger modal and load data to it
   // get_details.php serve the data

    $(".your_comment_button").click(function(e){
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('enq_id');
            $.ajax({
              type:'GET',
              url:'get_deatils.php?id='+id, 
              success:function(data){
                 $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').html(data);
                 $('#myModal').modal('show');
              }
           });

        });
    });
```

and your get_details.php looks like

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","yourdb");
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$enq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT enquiry.* from enquiry  Where id=$id");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($enq);
?>
<div class="form-style-10">
  Hi
  <?php  echo $row['name'];?>
</div>
```

Comment: its showing error, in the query in getdetails.php, the select query is wrong

Comment: check your db connection also, can you comment your error?

Comment: the ajax modal is not closing when i click around the screen

Comment: i think you are not using a bootstrap model ,use a simple bootstrap model